# VBA - Adding a listbox to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, listbox, userform

I've been searching around online, and just want to know how to add a bunch of ListBoxes from my Userform to my array. Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim LBArray() As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ReDim LBArray(7) As Variant
FirstNameTextBox.Clear
LastNameTextBox.Clear
HotelCIDate.Clear
HotelCODate.Clear
HotelNameBox.Clear
HotelConfStatus.Clear
HotelConfNumber.Clear

LBArray(0) = FirstNameTextBox
LBArray(1) = LastNameTextBox
LBArray(2) = HotelNameBox
LBArray(3) = HotelCIDate
LBArray(4) = HotelCODate
LBArray(5) = HotelConfStatus
LBArray(6) = HotelConfNumber

End Sub
```

This should work, but it doesn't actually add the listboxes to the array. All the elements are either "" or Null, and I can't modify the ListBox objects from the array. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I might ask **why** you're doing this, since the Form's members (controls such as ListBoxes, TextBoxes, etc.) are available to reference by name. Putting them in an array seems like an unnecessary extra step...

Comment: It is an unnecessary extra step, mainly meant to save some code later. I don't /need/ it, but it is still helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A listbox is an `Object`, so you need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object, otherwise it will return the object's default property (which in this case I think is the `.Value` property)

```
Set LBArray(2) = HotelNameBox
```

Etc.

I don't think it's really necessary to do this, and actually it seems unnecessary and confusing! Later in your code, you're going to need to refer to `ListBox(i)` or to the objects by name.

If you need to iterate over the listboxes and perform some operations on them, you can always do:

```
Dim ctrl as MSForms.Control

For each ctrl in UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
       ** Code to do something with each listbox
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I didn't realize you can scroll through the controls of a form like that, it helps out immensely! Thanks very much!